# $.each loop to fill json array not working

Tags: jquery, arrays, json, push, each

I am trying to fill a json array to send to the server over ajax. However, it's not working and i'm not really sure why. Here's the code:

```
    var form = $('.dash-name-form');


    form.serializeArray();

    input = [];

    $.each(form[0], function(){

        input.push({

            this.name : this.value
        });
    });

    console.log(JSON.stringify(input));
```

It works when I do the following:

```
    $.each(form[0], function(){

        input.push({

            'name' : this.name, 
            'value': this.value
        });
    });
```

But I'd really like the more simplified output from the first block in order to work more nicely with the back end framework I'm using (laravel's Input::json()->all() does not work with the second one).

All suggestions are greatly appreciated. Thanks y'all.

Comment: Are you aware of the fact that the `serializeArray` call there does nothing?

Comment: set a value for the array returned from `serializeArray()`, `var formData = form.serializeArray(); Skip pushing the data to a separate array, unless you need to filter or process the data.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pay attention to the fact that functions like `serializeArray` return value and if you don't store the value in a variable or using it directly,  the call is useless

Try this one instead.
It will get you the data of the form in plain object

```
var all =$('.dash-name-form').serializeArray(),
      data = {};

$.each (all, function (key, val){
      data [key]  = val;
});

console.log (data);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
$.each(form.serializeArray(), function(){
    var obj = {}; 
    obj[this.name] = this.value;
    input.push(obj);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
input.push({
    this.name : this.value
});
```

This looks like it would be a problem. `this.name` will be interpreted as the key, not what you might expect (this is the same as doing `{"this.name": this.value}`).

```
var foo = "bar";
var x = {
  foo: "test"  
}

console.log(x);
```